# how to populate the alertdialog from the values queried from database?

Tags: android, android-inflate, android-view, android-alertdialog

Right now I can only see the fetched values when I press OK button of the dialog. But I want to see it when the alertdialog appears. I know I have put the display code inside the .setPositiveButton("OK", But even when I tried putting it before that, it didnt work. I some how have idea that i need to make use of this setview(addView) but dont know how. Please help me.

```
enter code here
private void populateFields() {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_country, null);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Edit country/year")
    .setView(addView)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
    Cursor c = 
         getContentResolver().query                                                                   (CONTENT_URI.buildUpon                                             ().appendPath(String.valueOf(mRowId)).build(), null, null, null, null);
    /* Read alert input */
    EditText editCountry =(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editCountry);
    EditText editYear =(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editYear);
    //System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("country")));
    editCountry.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("country")));
    editYear.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("year")));
                }
                })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
      // ignore, just dismiss
    }
})
    .show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting your code right after you have inflated the view. Something like this :

```
private void populateFields() {
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_country, null);

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(String.valueOf(mRowId)).build(), null, null, null, null);
/* Read alert input */
EditText editCountry =(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editCountry);
EditText editYear =(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editYear);

editCountry.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("country")));
editYear.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("year")));

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Edit country/year")
.setView(addView)
.setPositiveButton("OK",null)
.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
.show();
}
```